# Refactor Node.JS callbacks for DRY code

Tags: javascript, node.js, refactoring, dry

Both find calls inside the ifs have callbacks that start by function(e, docs).
What would be a clean way to refactor it to be DRYer? 
Thanks.

```
    if (connection_id == null) {
        id_connectionsCollection.find({}, {}, function (e, docs) {
            if (e) {
                return callback(e);
            }
            var connectionDetails = null;
            if (docs == null || docs.length == 0) {//if no connections found, use default from config
                connectionDetails = defaultConnectionDetails
            }
            else {

                connectionDetails = docs[0];//just get the first one
            }

            return callback(null, connectionDetails);
        });

    }
    else {
        id_connectionsCollection.find({name: connection_id}, {sort: {updated_at: -1}}, function (e, docs) {
            if (e) {
                return callback(e);
            }
            var connectionDetails = null;
            if (docs == null || docs.length == 0) {
                connectionDetails = defaultConnectionDetails;
            }
            else {

                connectionDetails = docs[0];//just get the first one
            }
            return callback(null, connectionDetails);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way to DRY your code is to extract your callback to a named function that can be passed as your callback on the last arg of your `find` method:

```
 // Can probably think of a better name here...
 doCallback = function(e, docs) {
      if (e)
        return callback(e);

      var connectionDetails = null;

      if (docs == null || docs.length == 0)
        connectionDetails = defaultConnectionDetails;
      else 
        connectionDetails = docs[0];//just get the first one

      return callback(null, connectionDetails);
}

if (connection_id == null)
  id_connectionsCollection.find({}, {}, doCallback);
else 
  id_connectionsCollection.find({name: connection_id}, {sort: {updated_at: -1}}, doCallback);
```